# NoMethodError in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm following the getting started rails tutorial at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
And the code is the same as here, I don't get it.
What am I doing wrong at "comments.post" in line ten?

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show

Showing /Users/franklinexpress/rails_projects/wal/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
```

where line #10 raised:

```
undefined method `post' for #<Comment:0x007ff05072c110>
```

Extracted source (around line #10):

```
7:      <b>Comment:</b>
8:      <%= comment.comment %>
9:      </p>
10:         <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
11:                         :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
12:                         :method => :delete %>
13:
```

Comment: Post your Comment model please.

Comment: I don't see that format for link_to in that guide.  Other than form_for, exactly where in the guide is that ?

Comment: That code is under section `9 Deleting Comments`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this from `7.2 Associating Models`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

that should generate the `post` method on the `comment` instance.